# One <DIV id="Div1"> ... Two fuctions ... javascript virtualkeyboard

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I need help with my virtual keyboard, On my keyboard there is a DIV that i use to make button value="MAG" work in javascript but i'm using the same DIV to make the keyboard work and write but using one Div with the same id="Div1" doesn't work for me ... so i have to chose between ((Writing using the keyboard .... or changing the keyboard from MAG to MIN )) not both !! .... here is my code and and as you can see you can only write using the keyboard but you can not use MAG button .... i'm sorry for my bad English ...

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#Div1{
 display: block;

}

#Div2 {
  display: none;

}

.divs
{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">

*{margin:0;padding:0;}
*{margin:0;padding:0;}</style>
<script>
(function() {
   'use strict';
   var i,c;
function init(){ 
/* get all the input elements within the div whose id is "keyboard */
   i=document.getElementById('Div1').getElementsByTagName('input'); 
/* loop through all the elements */   
for(c=0;c<i.length;c++) {
/* find all the the input type="button" elements */
if(i[c].type==='button') { 
 /* add an onclick handler to each of them  and set the function to call */
   i[c].addEventListener('onclick',makeClickHandler(c));
   }
  }

/* this is the type="reset" input */
document.getElementById('clear').onclick=function() {
/* remove all the characters from the input type="text" element */
   document.getElementById('text').value='';
  }
 }

function makeClickHandler(c) {
   i[c].onclick=function() {
/* find the non-text button  which has an id */
if(i[c].id==='back') {
/* remove last character from the input the type="text" element using regular expression */
   document.getElementById('text').value=
   document.getElementById('text').value.replace(/.$/,'');
 }
/* find the text buttons */
else {
/* add characters to the input type="text" element */
   document.getElementById('text').value+=this.value.toLowerCase();
   }
  };
 }

   window.addEventListener?
   window.addEventListener('load',init,false):
   window.attachEvent('onload',init);
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>



<div id="Div1">

<div>
<input value="1" type="button">
<input value="2" type="button">
<input value="3" type="button">
<input value="4" type="button">
<input value="5" type="button">
<input value="6" type="button">
<input value="7" type="button">
<input value="8" type="button">
<input value="9" type="button">
<input value="0" type="button">
<input value="Borrar" type="button">
</div><div>
<input value="q" type="button">
<input value="w" type="button">
<input value="e" type="button">
<input value="r" type="button">
<input value="t" type="button">
<input value="y" type="button">
<input value="u" type="button">
<input value="i" type="button">
<input value="o" type="button">
<input value="p" type="button">
<input value="`" type="button">
<input value="+" type="button">
</div><div><input value="a" type="button">
<input value="s" type="button">
<input value="d" type="button">
<input value="f" type="button">
<input value="g" type="button">
<input value="h" type="button">
<input value="j" type="button">
<input value="k" type="button">
<input value="l" type="button">
<input value="ñ" type="button">
<input value="´" type="button">
<input value="ç" type="button">
</div><div>
<input value="&lt;" type="button">
<input value="z" type="button">
<input value="x" type="button">
<input value="c" type="button">
<input value="v" type="button">
<input value="b" type="button">
<input value="n" type="button">
<input value="m" type="button">
<input value="+" type="button">
<input value="." type="button">
<input value="-" type="button">
<input disabled="disabled" value=" " type="button">
</div><div>
<input id="Button1" value="MAG." type="button"  onclick="switchVisible();">
<input value=" " type="button">
<input id="Button1" value="MAG." type="button"  onclick="switchVisible();">
</div></div>
<div id="Div2" style="display:none" class="keyboard"><div>
<input value="!" type="button">
<input value="&quot;" type="button">
<input value="·" type="button">
<input value="$" type="button">
<input value="%" type="button">
<input value="&amp;" type="button">
<input value="/" type="button">
<input value="(" type="button">
<input value=")" type="button">
<input value="=" type="button">
<input value="Borrar" type="button">
</div><div>
<input value="Q" type="button">
<input value="W" type="button">
<input value="E" type="button">
<input value="R" type="button">
<input value="T" type="button">
<input value="Y" type="button">
<input value="U" type="button">
<input value="I" type="button">
<input value="O" type="button">
<input value="P" type="button">
<input value="^" type="button">
<input value="*" type="button">
</div><div>
<input value="A" type="button">
<input value="S" type="button">
<input value="D" type="button">
<input value="F" type="button">
<input value="G" type="button">
<input value="H" type="button">
<input value="J" type="button">
<input value="K" type="button">
<input value="L" type="button">
<input value="Ñ" type="button">
<input value="¨" type="button">
<input value="Ç" type="button">
</div><div>
<input value="&gt;" type="button">
<input value="Z" type="button">
<input value="X" type="button">
<input value="C" type="button">
<input value="V" type="button">
<input value="B" type="button">
<input value="N" type="button">
<input value="M" type="button">
<input value=";" type="button">
<input value=":" type="button">
<input value="_" type="button">
<input disabled="disalbed" value="" type="button">
</div><div>
<input id="Button1" value="Min." type="button" onclick="switchVisible();">
<input value=" " type="button">
<input id="Button1" value="Min." type="button" onclick="switchVisible();">
</div></div></div></div>
<div>
<label>Track Search</label> - <input id="text" type="text" readonly="readonly">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function switchVisible() {
     var div1=document.getElementById('Div1');
     var div2=document.getElementById('Div2');
     
      if (div1 !== undefined && div2 !== undefined) {
       div1.style.display = div2.style.display === '' ? 'none' : div2.style.display === 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
       div2.style.display = div1.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
      }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues that need to be addressed:

Major issues:

- Console JS error - there is no button with an ID of "clear".
- I didn't see a button with an ID of "back"

  - I'm guessing it's the "Borrar" button, but it lacks an ID.
  - It would also need to be skipped by the loop in the `init` function discussed in the next point.
- There are 4 `<input id="Button1"...`:

  - IDs need to be unique.
  - But these buttons do need a class or id to prevent the `makeClickHandler` from attaching an `onclick` function and overriding the inline `onclick` defintiion.

    ```
    /* find all the the input type="button" elements */
    if(i[c].type==='button' && (i[c].id !== "Button1" || i[c].id !== "back")) { 
        /* add an onclick handler to each of them  and set the function to call */
        i[c].addEventListener('onclick',makeClickHandler(c));
    }
    ```

Minor issues:

- Move the [IIFE script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) in the `<head>` to the bottom of the page; then you won't need to add an event listener for "onload".
- The code is *almost* unreadable. Please use indention properly and be consistent!
- There's an input with a misspelled disable - `disabled="disalbed"`
- By convention, element id's shouldn't start with a capital letter.
- Avoid using `onclick` or any inline javascript. This is called a [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).
- Brush up/learn about [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation); it'll make the code cleaner.